# Firebase Error in console log: firebase-database-connection error search

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep getting this error whenever I try running my application (build gradle sync*):

```
"Could not find any version that matches 
com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1]. Search in build.gradle files"
```

I have no idea what firebase-database-connection is and when I comment out the implementation for firebase core and all of that, there's no errors?.

App level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.flavor"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything is updated completely (16.0.1 v 16.0.0) and I have no idea what's wrong? Does anyone else have this error?

--

More Error messages of topic:

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base are available.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base are available.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base are available.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base are available.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[16.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base are available.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.0].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1].
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Open File
Show Details

Open File goes to the app level build.gradle and Show Details doesn't do anything (broken button?)

Comment: 
I've tried everything too! I've even tried invalidating caches and restarting everything but nope. I've also learned that I'm getting this error for other applications I've opened / started working on as well that include Firebase?

Answer (score -1):

Well in my case I was getting this error when using offline gradle mode means I was using locally stored gradle scripts. Change or update your gradle version in build.gradle and then allow it to update over the internet. Your issue should get resolved.